# How much sourdough (by weight) should I put in a 9x5 loaf pan?

Tags: bread, sourdough

How much sourdough (by weight) should I put in a 9x5 loaf pan?

I would like it as fluffy as possible but still a "full" loaf.

I'm using regular sourdough that just consists of culture, all purpose flour, water, and salt.

My loaf pan is the standard 9x5 inch, 1.5 quart Anchor Hocking glass pan. I do grease it in shortening before I put the dough in to make it non-stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9x5 loaf pan I consider to be a standard 2 lb (or 900 gram) loaf when portioning dough. Your preferences may vary, but that's a starting point.